# Reading values using jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this javascript code for google analytics;

```
<script>        
ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
  'id': '3417327', 
  'affiliation': '',  
  'revenue': '59.90', 
  'shipping': '99.00',    
  'tax': '0'          
});
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
  'id': '3417327', 
  'name': 'Sample',
  'sku': '86454',
  'category': '',
  'price': '59.90',
  'quantity': '1' 
});
ga('ecommerce:send');
</script>
```

Please note that I can not modify the above code at all. Its is a template section that is hard coded, and I will be adding the required code in the footer section to get the output.

What I need is to use javascript or jquery to read the values of id, name, sku, affliation, revenue all and print it say in console.log. I tried by best to get some code but it all failed for me.

Can anyone help me I will highly appreciate

Answer (score 2):

Try using intermediate variables for your parameters :

```
var myObject = {
  'id': '3417327', 
  'name': 'Sample',
  'sku': '86454',
  'category': '',
  'price': '59.90',
  'quantity': '1' 
};
ga('ecommerce:addItem', myObject);
console.log(myObject)//will print the object in the console.
```

Comment: Well the thing is I can not modify anything from the code that I added. So whatever code that I need to be used will go below this code and than I can use any function. So based on this your code will not work correct?